# Specify max and min in NumberInput widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a form that is using `NumberInput` widget to accept a rating for a Song from the user. The number should be between 0-5. My Song model has a `MaxValueValidator` but I want the `NumberInput` widget to show options only from 0-5.

Comment: So what does it do currently? what isn't working?

Comment: Currently, it imposes no upper limit on the number it accepts. Only after I submit the form, does the validator kick in and raise an error which is displayed by the form asking the user to enter between 0-5

Comment: Thats what the validator is for, server side validation, if you want  client side validation you need to write that. Django can't help you there

Comment: Isn't there any attribute I can modify for the widget displayed so that it shows numbers only till 5? Something like : `form.fields['rating'].widget.max_value=5`

Comment: No because django doesn't handle client side validation

Comment: @Sayse, client does handle required client side validation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your form you can add min and max value which atleast shows the user the value should be between the limits.

```
rating = forms.CharField(label='Rating', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'min':1,'max': '5','type': 'number'}))
```

Comment: This also restricts the widget to display only upto `5`. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As shown below, by setting **"max"(for maximum number)**, **"min"(for minimum number)** to **"forms.NumberInput()"**, you can do what you want to do:

```py
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'rate': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'max': '5',    # For maximum number
                'min': '0',    # For minimum number
            }),
        }
```